# Making map with all 48 contiguous states resized so they each have equal land area using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, united-states, cartogram

How can I make a map in QGIS where I have all 48 contiguous states but they're resized so they each have equal land area?

It's important that I do this without distorting shape, so that they're still easily recognizable as the states that they are, but all of a sudden we have, say, Delaware XXL, looking like it's the same size as Texas. I don't know of a projection that accomplishes this, and simply making buffers won't work due to overlaps.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "cartogram"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating cartograms as you can see on this site https://worldmapper.org/ there is a QGIS pluging named [Cartogram3](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cartogram3/). A cartogram is

> a thematic map of a set of features (countries, provinces, etc.), in
> which their geographic size is altered to be directly proportional to
> a selected ratio-level variable, such as travel time, population, or
> GNP. Geographic space itself is thus warped, sometimes extremely, in
> order to visualize the distribution of the variable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartogram

Another option is the standalone, open-source software [ScapeToad](http://scapetoad.choros.place/) which is easy to use and outputs shapefiles that you can re-import to QGIS. See also [GIS SE about ScapeToad](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=scapetoad).